# Isotope elements only refresh on page refresh

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-isotope

I am trying out the isotope jquery to rearrange a portfolio.

I want the website to be responsive so I have set the elements in the container to be 22% wide.

However all looks fine when I load the page for the first time. Or refresh it. But if I resize the page, the elements width changes fine but they have a large gap between them.

The same thing happens when testing it on the ipad roasting between portrait and landscape.

Why don't they automatically move into their new position until the page is refreshed? Here is an example. The section I am talking about is the 'featured' boxes.

[Http://www.comeinside.co.uk](http://www.comeinside.co.uk)

Comment: What what code/markup did you use to declare this 22% wide rule?

Comment: Just CSS rule for each element. Each element has the 'grid_3'stylesheet attached which has width=22% and margin left/right=1%

Comment: Since your asking about a jQuery plugin here, you should include the relevant JS you wrote that calls this plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Never ever used this plugin, but after a little googling it looks like his demo does what you want:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/fluid-responsive.html

```
// update columnWidth on window resize
$(window).smartresize(function(){
  $container.isotope({
    // update columnWidth to a percentage of container width
    masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
  });
});
```